# ColdFusion MX 6 query returns (instantly) blank error at the cfquery level when more than ~50 records are returned from an MSSQL source

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-6

Very interesting issue we've run into with a scheduled task that has been failing.  Here is a screenshot with verbose exceptions enabled (using a brand new test datasource with no special advanced settings):

here is an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/puKEd.png

Example of the query:

```
select e.firstname,e.lastname,e.department,e.salesnumber
from employees e
```

Couple notes:

1. The datasource validates in the CFAdmin (and we've also rebuilt it using the FQDN and IP to no avail).
2. We're able to log in with the same user/pass directly in SSMS and run the query which returns about 18,000 rows.
3. The error is returned **INSTANTLY** which is completely atypical of any general timeout error I've run into.

If we slightly modify the query to include something like TOP:

```
select TOP 20 e.firstname,e.lastname,e.department,e.salesnumber
from employees e
```

The query runs with absolutely no issue.  I've been able to use another table in another database on the database server that is normally used for this web server and have no problems with larger recordcounts.  They take a while to process, which is normal, while this query returns this immediately if we ask for more than about 50 records.  Between about 50-70 it alternates between throwing this error or actually running and timing out/crashing Jrun, requiring a service restart.

We've even changed the query into a stored procedure and used  and  to call it, assuming that may ColdFusion was having problem interpreting the query in-line but that still returns the same results.  The most confusing part is that this error is received so quickly (the query even has time to run) depending on the number of results we ask it for.

Comment: Please tell me it's not actually 6.0 you're running, and you meant 6.x and it's actually 6.1? 6.0 is basically an alpha product, and not fit for production. It sounds like there's an incompat with your DB drivers, but you have zero chance of this being fixed. Try updating the drivers. I doubt your 6.x licence would cover any current versions of the drivers CF ships with though, so you'll need to grab some from the DB vendor.

Comment: First, which database and version are you using? If you cannot find newer drivers, there was a *macromedia* driver update a while back. You can still access it through [waybackmachine.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20050306164416/http://www.macromedia.com/cfusion/knowledgebase/index.cfm?id=tn_18807). Also a) Have you checked the log files? b) Have there been any recent changes to this db table? c) This should not make a difference, but .. I noticed your sample query above does not match the one in the screen shot. Have you actually tried specifying the column names instead of `select *` ..?

Comment: Your screenshot does not show the error message.  It only shows the cfquery tag.

Comment: @DanBracuk - It does, but I believe the error "message" is blank. user2548181 - What does the stack trace report?

Comment: Have you tried isolating this query on a stripped down test page? It could be that there is something else trying to run that's using resources.